# How to bookmark current line right before jumping to beginning of buffer and get back?

Tags: bookmarks

I am working on Python files and jump to beginning section to fix some imports and come back to point I am working on.

I want to use `Bookmark`, when I make a change on beginning of the file and come-back to the latest line I am working on. I was using `ctrl+u+space`, but I need to press multiple times to get back to latest point.

For following condition if possible:

- When I jump to  beginning of the buffer, also automatically I want to add a bookmark to the latest line I am working on.
- Afterwards I made some changes on the `import` section, I want to get back to the latest bookmark (which is the right before I jumped), with a keybinding without entering its name into `Jump to bookmark:`.

Setup:

```
(global-set-key "\C-x\ ,"  'beginning-of-buffer);

(defadvice bookmark-jump (after bookmark-jump activate)
  (let ((latest (bookmark-get-bookmark bookmark)))
    (setq bookmark-alist (delq latest bookmark-alist))
    (add-to-list 'bookmark-alist latest)))
```

---

Example:

```
1   | import hello
2   | import world
...
20  | import python
...
1000| line_I_am_working_on = 100
```

I am on line 1000. Than I pressed `Ctrl+x+,` to jump to beginning of the buffer. Than I go to line-20 by pressing line-down (`Ctrl+p`) and make a change. As final step I want to jump back to line 1000.

Comment: Instead of using bookmarks, you should use the [basic mark mechanism](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mark.html#Mark): `beginning-of-buffer` which is bound to `M-<` pushes a mark with the current position - you can then get back to it with `C-x C-x`.

Comment: `C-x C-x` gets back to the position but it also highlights it from beginning of the file to the position. Is it possible to disable highlighting when `C-x C-x` is pressed?

Comment: C-g will get rid of the highlighting. Or you can disable `transient-mark-mode`, although IMO it's far too useful to disable. I use C-g.

Comment: Is it possible to do following: I can bind `C-x C-x` into `C-x C-x` and followed by (`C-g`  or `C-SPC C-SPC`)

Comment: Just use `C-u C-x C-x` instead.

Comment: @NickD Thanks `C-u C-x C-x` works great! Also it there any way to jump to latest bookmark without entering an input for `Jump to bookmark:.` on the mini-buffer

Comment: Please do not ask new questions in comments: create a new question.